# AJAX Post throws Broken Pipe and results in GET

Tags: django

I am sending a POST request via AJAX to Django server, after receiving the POST request by django it throws a "Broken Pipe error" and also initiates a GET request to same url but searching for "csrfmiddlewaretoken". Is this normal? How to avoid the GET request?

```
 [script]

<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/js_cookie.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/csrf.js' %}">
</script>
<script>
function myfunc(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "help",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "hello": "hello",
        },
    })
}
</script>

[views.py]
def help_view(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render(request, 'jsnapy_wizard/help.html')
if request.method == 'POST':
    print request.POST
    return render(request, 'jsnapy_wizard/help.html')

[urls.py]
urlpatterns = [
url(r'help', help_view, name='help'),

Error

<QueryDict: {u'hello': [u'hello']}>
[12/Jul/2018 07:17:37] "POST /help HTTP/1.1" 200 670
[2018-07-12 07:17:37,677] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 49808)

[12/Jul/2018 07:17:37] "GET /help?csrfmiddlewaretoken=nPvGEmGRGLhzGi7X3zRDFhElKLOaMR1CQbZoUA5lwPCCWbdkyVFEPLeE4vzfQ9pC HTTP/1.1" 200 670
```

Comment: your `url` in ajax function is wrong. Please call url using `{% url %}`

Comment: Tried below but still the same                                                                                           url: "{% url 'jsnapy_wizard:help' %}",

Comment: Please upload your full code. Where do you call `myfunc()`?

Comment: <body>
    <form>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="test">Input</label>
        <input type="text" id="test">
        <button type="submit" onclick="myfunc()">Submit</button>
    </form>
</script>
<script>
    function myfunc(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'jsnapy_wizard:help' %}",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                "hello": "hello",
            },
        })
    }
</script>
</body>

Comment: I guess get request is send after onclick function. You need to add `return false` after myfunc() then `get` request will not send.

Comment: can you please help me to place it where exactly...

Comment: Ok I'll right answer about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few problems.

1. If you want to send only ajax, you don't have to use `form`. You're form is with `method=GET` and it will send get request when submit.

So just remove form or add `return false` in submit. Or just add `e.preventDefault()` with id. I'll edit using this way.

2. add `csrfmiddlewaretoken` in your ajax.
3. change your url with `{% url %}`. Maybe `{% url 'help' %}` (you have to set your own url)
4. Also you will add `success` or `error` after accept ajax return. I'll add  just a example. Then you will send `JsonResonpse` from view, not render the whole template.

   ```
   <body> 
       <form> 
           {% csrf_token %} 
           <label for="test">Input</label> 
           <input type="text" id="test"> 
           <button type="submit" id="ajaxBtn">Submit</button>
       </form> 
       <script> 
       function myfunc(){
           $.ajax({
               url: "{% url 'help' %}",
               type: 'POST',
               data: {
                   "hello": "hello",
                   "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"
               },
               success: function(response) {
                   console.log(response);
               },
               error: function(rs, e) {
                   console.log(e);
               }
           })
       }
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#ajaxBtn').click(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               myfunc();
           })
       })
       </script> 
   </body>
   ```

In your view,

```
def help_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'jsnapy_wizard/help.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # make sure that 'POST' and 'ajax' is different
        if request.is_ajax():
            print 'ajax work'
            data = {
                'your_data': 'your_data_example',
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: It solved the problem I had, but now the data entered into the input element stays there after clicking the submit button. Tried reloading the location, with success in AJAX no luck. Any clues?